# XML Schema with datatype

Tags: xml

I have an XML Document with data

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

    <!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->

    <bookstore>

        <book category="COOKING">

            <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>

            <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>

            <year>2005</year>

            <price>30.00</price>

        </book>

        <book category="CHILDREN">

            <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>

            <author>J K. Rowling</author>

            <year>2005</year>

            <price>29.99</price>

        </book>

        <book category="WEB">

            <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>

            <author>James McGovern</author>

            <author>Per Bothner</author>

            <author>Kurt Cagle</author>

            <author>James Linn</author>

            <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>

            <year>2005</year>

            <price>49.99</price>

        </book>

        <book category="WEB">

            <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>

            <author>Erik T. Ray</author>

            <year>2005</year>

            <price>39.95</price>

        </book>

 </bookstore>
```

I want to set the `<price>` data type as Integer.
Please help me out to get a solution.

Comment: why price as integer? should not be float?

Comment: @DavorMlinaric : Yes It can be float also..just want to know how to set the datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use online tool to generate schema.

http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="bookstore">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Edited by XMLSpy®</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="book" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="title">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="lang" use="optional"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="author" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:short" name="year"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:float" name="price"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="category" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```